# Pythonic way to index without losing dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice, dimensions

```
data = np.zeros((5, 16, 16))
```

I would like to access a slice of size 1 of this numpy data array. It might be helpful to define what I don't want:

```
>>> data[2].shape
(16, 16)
```

Instead, I want to keep the dimensionality the same. A couple of ways come to mind here:

```
>>> np.expand_dims(data[2], 0).shape
(1, 16, 16)

>>> data[2:3].shape
(1, 16, 16)

>>> data[None, 2].shape
(1, 16, 16)
```

Which one of these options is more pythonic, or is there a better solution here?

Comment: `result = data[2:3]` seems the simplest approach to me, since you're just slicing along the first axis which is what you want

Comment: true, the intuition is good here. My main problem with this solutions is readability - I feel like the form does suggest a different function and at first glance, it is not obvious that this results in a singleton dimension

Comment: I favor the slice, since it's more obvious that you are trying to preserve an existing dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with a list of indices with a single element:

```
>>> data[[2]].shape
(1, 16, 16)
```

As for which is more pythonic, that is more opinion-based than anything.

---

**Note**: This method will create a copy of the data instead of a view into the same data since arbitrary indices might not result in a contiguous view. This is explained in detail in the question [Avoid copying when indexing a numpy arrays using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819799/avoid-copying-when-indexing-a-numpy-arrays-using-lists)

Comment: except I think this will make a copy.  The others make views.

Comment: @hpaulj, hmm seems you are correct. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the heads up