# Sort one list to to make two lists have correct order correspondence

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy, dictionary

I have two lists, e.g.

```
coords = [2, 0, 1, 4, 3]
value = [1, 9, 3, 3, 0]
```

where the first one is a series of coordinates, and the second one is a series of values corresponding to the coordinates, e.g. coordinate `'2'` corresponds to the value `'1'`, coords `'0'` gives value `'9'`.

Now, I would like to sort `coords` **but** keep the order of `value` unchanged, such that the smallest `coords` element corresponds to the smallest element in `value`, and so on. The desired output would be:

```
coords_new = [1, 4, 2, 3, 0]
value = [1, 9, 3, 3, 0] # unchanged
```

where `'0' -> '0', '1' -> '1', '2' -> '3', '3' -> '3', '4' -> '9'`.
Any ideas to do that? You can return `coords_new`, or the indices that reorders the `coords` as answer.

Edit:
If possible, I prefer we can return the indices that reorders the original `coords`, i.e. return the `idx` such that `coords[idx] = coords_new`.

Thanks a lot!

Zhihao

Comment: Just use `np.argsort` to generate the sorting indices.

Comment: Well, I don't think the np.argsort can directly get the desired output... Any ideas?

Comment: In my case, the coords  should be unique. But if you can get a solution of general case that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are one and a half solutions using argsort. The `kind='mergesort'` kwd argument is only necessary if you require a stable sort. In your example, an unstable sort may also yield `coords_new == [1, 4, 3, 2, 0]`. If that is not a problem you can omit the kwd arg and allow numpy to use a faster sort algorithm.

```
import numpy as np

coords = [2, 0, 1, 4, 3]
value = [1, 9, 3, 3, 0]

coords, value = map(np.asanyarray, (coords, value))

vidx = value.argsort(kind='mergesort') # mergesort is stable, i.e. it  
                                       # preserves the order of equal elements

# direct method:
coords_new = np.empty_like(coords)
coords_new[vidx] = np.sort(coords)

# method yielding idx
idx = np.empty_like(vidx)
idx[vidx] = coords.argsort(kind='mergesort')
```

The second method yields `idx` such that `coords_new == coords[idx]`.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to first create the mapping between the objects and then use this mapping combined with index:

```
coords = [2, 0, 1, 4, 3]
value = [1, 9, 3, 3, 0]

table = {k: v for k, v in zip(sorted(coords), sorted(value))}
print(table)
print(sorted(coords, key=lambda e: value.index(table[e])))
```

**Output**

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 9}
[1, 4, 2, 3, 0]
```

**Note**

This method assumes `coords` only contains unique values. For the general case you could generate the pairs `(c, v)` of the mapping an sort by the index value of v in value:

```
pairs = [(k, v) for k, v in zip(sorted(coords), sorted(value))]
result = [k for k, _ in sorted(pairs, key=lambda e: value.index(e[1]))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4, 2, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to get the indices `idx` which reorders the `coords` to the new one? i.e. we can get `coords_new` from `coords[idx]`.

Comment: You could use the index function on the new list.

Comment: Look at [Rearrange columns of numpy 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20265229/674039) for the permutation bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a numpy answer since you've tagged numpy:

```
>>> x = np.argsort(value)
>>> x[x]
array([1, 4, 2, 3, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems good. But is there a way not return coords_new but directly return idx such that coords[idx] = coords_new?

Comment: Yes, but perhaps you should edit the question, including the expected result, so that the difference is clearer. It's not good to use an example data where it looks the same either way, that's just unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: After you have edited the question, I will post a solution for the `idx`.