# Move position of row in Numpy 2d array

Tags: numpy

Given Array:

```
np.array([[1, 2],
          [3, 4],
          [5, 6],
          [7, 8],
          [9, 10]])
```

If I want to move row at indice 1 to indice 3.
The output should be:

```
[[1, 2],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8],
 [3, 4],
 [9, 10]]
```

If I want to move row at indice 4 to indice 1.
The output should be:

```
[[1, 2],
 [9, 10],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

What is the **fastest** way to do this moving operation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rearrange columns of numpy 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265229/rearrange-columns-of-numpy-2d-array)

Comment: Speed may depend on how many rows have to be moved (or shifted up/down).  Conceptually the simplest is to just make a new array with advanced indexing (as @norok2 shows).  An in-place change might be faster if it just switches a few rows of a much larger array (but your examples move 3 of 5, and 4 of 5).

Comment: Yeah, speed is certainly proportional to the number of rows affected. Advanced indexing accesses all array elements which is why it scales poorly when the rows increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, if you want to put row `i` at position `j`, then only rows in the range between `i` and `j` are affected; rows outside do not need to be changed. And this change is basically a `roll` operation. For items `a,b,c,d,e`, putting item at `i=1` to `j=3` means that `b,c,d` will become `c,d,b`, giving us `a,c,d,b,e`. The shift is either `-1` or `+1` depending on if `i<j`.

```
i, j = 1,3
i, j, s = (i, j, -1) if i<j else (j, i, 1)
arr[i:j+1] = np.roll(arr[i:j+1],shift=s,axis=0)
```

Comment: Of course. While simply plugging in the correctly permuted indices is easy, you're computing those indices by hand; this scales very poorly. Imagine you have an array of size (5000,5000), it's impossible to write the indices by hand like you wrote (0,2,3,1,4). Instead, you would then need to write some sort of logic that creates the correctly permuted indices, which will consume a memory overhead equivalent of an array of length 5000.

Comment: I think your comment should go in norok's answer. But you are right, my array is large therefore I believe your solution is optimal.

Comment: @Mercury That says nothing about speed. See the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about `tuple()` indexing on first axis?

E.g.:

```
arr[(0, 2, 3, 1, 4), :]
```

and:

```
arr[(0, 4, 1, 2, 3), :]
```

for your expected outputs, respectively.

---

For a way of generating the indices starting from the two indices you could use the following:

```
def inner_roll(arr, first, last, axis):
    stop = last + 1
    indices = list(range(arr.shape[axis]))
    indices.insert(first, last)
    indices.pop(last + 1)
    slicing = tuple(
        slice(None) if i != axis else indices
        for i, d in enumerate(arr.shape))
    return arr[slicing]
```

For inputs that are relatively small along the axis on which you are operating (such as for the input in the question) this is quite fast.

Comparing it with a slightly polished version of [@Mercury's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877806/5218354) to wrap it in a function and to make it work correctly for arbitrary `axis`:

```
import numpy as np


def inner_roll2(arr, first, last, axis):
    if first > last:
        first, last = last, first
        shift = 1
    else:
        shift = -1
    slicing = tuple(
        slice(None) if i != axis else slice(first, last + 1)
        for i, d in enumerate(arr.shape))
    arr[slicing] = np.roll(arr[slicing], shift=shift, axis=axis)
    return arr
```

and getting some timings:

```
funcs = inner_roll, inner_roll2
for n in (5, 50, 500):
    for m in (2, 20, 200):
        arr = np.arange(n * m).reshape((n, m))
        print(f'({n:<3d}, {m:<3d})', end='    ')
        for func in funcs:
            results = %timeit -o -q func(arr, 1, 2, 0)
            print(f'{func.__name__:>12s}  {results.best* 1e6:>7.3f} µs', end='    ')
        print()
# (5  , 2  )      inner_roll    5.613 µs     inner_roll2   15.393 µs    
# (5  , 20 )      inner_roll    5.592 µs     inner_roll2   15.468 µs    
# (5  , 200)      inner_roll    5.916 µs     inner_roll2   15.815 µs    
# (50 , 2  )      inner_roll   10.117 µs     inner_roll2   15.517 µs    
# (50 , 20 )      inner_roll   10.360 µs     inner_roll2   15.505 µs    
# (50 , 200)      inner_roll   12.067 µs     inner_roll2   15.886 µs    
# (500, 2  )      inner_roll   55.833 µs     inner_roll2   15.409 µs    
# (500, 20 )      inner_roll   57.364 µs     inner_roll2   15.319 µs    
# (500, 200)      inner_roll  194.408 µs     inner_roll2   15.731 µs
```

This indicate that `inner_roll()` is the fastest approach for your inputs.
However, `inner_roll2()` seems to scale much better with input sizes, and for even modest input sizes, this is already faster than `inner_roll()`.

Note that, while `inner_roll()` creates a copy, `inner_roll2()` works in-place (modifying the input `arr`). This behavior can be modified by adding `arr = arr.copy()` at the beginning of the body of `inner_roll2()`, which would make that function slower (of course) and its timings would then be much more affected by the value of `m` (the size of the non-rolled axes).

On the other hand, if you were to do multiple consecutive rolling operations, `inner_roll2()` timings would just stack up, while for `inner_roll()` you only need to do the expensive part once.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution by @Mercury but found that it is even faster to avoid the array copy associated with `np.roll()` and instead operate entirely in-place:

```
    if index < index2:
      a[index:index2], a[index2] = a[index + 1:index2 + 1], a[index].copy()
    elif index2 < index:
      a[index2 + 1:index + 1], a[index2] = a[index2:index], a[index].copy()
```